# php record not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am not able to insert record in mysql, here is html & php code

html

```
 <form id="fForm" action="insert_staff_2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="formTxtInput" onkeyup="getStaffId()"> 
    <option>Gender</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Male</option>
</select>
```

php

```
    include  '../mysql_connect.php';
$db = new DBConfig();
$conn = $db->getDbPDO();
if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_staff (gender) VALUES (?)";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($gender)); 
echo"record enterd";
}else{
echo"record Not enterd"; }
```

Comment: Any errors? Error reporting is on?

Comment: Post your database wrapper code; we can't tell what it does.

Comment: <?php

Class DBConfig {

 public function getDbPDO()    
 {
  $hostname = 'localhost';
  $username = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $dbname = 'db_dm';
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  return $dbh;

 }

}

Comment: $query="INSERT INTO tbl_staff VALUES('?')";
// the value ? will be inserted in the new column in tbl_staff

Comment: @AnassElFakir no, that is a place holder. See examples 2-6, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not passing any values from your form. Be sure to set the 'value' attributes in your options tag, like this:

```
<option value='1'>Gender</option>
<option value='2'>Female</option>
<option value='3'>Male</option>
```

Comment: i just made the form like that, but still not show or inserting, do i have to change my if(isset($_POST['gender']) accordingly ?

Comment: try to add a `var_dump($gender)`, after `$gender = $_POST['gender'];` to check if the variable has got the value from the form

Answer (score 0):

verify your html form :

```
<form id="fForm" action="insert_staff_2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="formTxtInput" onkeyup="getStaffId()"> 
<option value="">Gender</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: why post an answer equal to another posted 20 minutes ago ?